# How to create a views that display all the publish content type as one output per user

Tags: views, nodes, users

Intro : I have created a two different content types because I needed two different moderation process for those two content type, each of those content type are limited to 1 per user. Those content are "Projet Description" and "Projet Images".

Now I need to combine those two content types into one with views so I can show the user projet and is related images. The problem I have for the moment when I group result together by UID is that the two node hare display separately and I see a Title for the Projet but I also see a Title for the Images.

**What I need is :**

USER 1
Title : My Projet Titre
first image for this project: (image1)

USER 2
Title : My Super Projet
first image for this project: (image1)

**What I have for the moment is :**

USER 1
Title : My Projet Title

Title : Images for the Projet
(image 1)(image 2)(image 3)

USER 2
Title : My Super Projet

Title : Images for the Projet
(image 1)(image 2)(image 3)

PS: I try to keep that as one question but I also need to have a exposed taxonomy filter for Projet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally did that with Relation module. I was assuming I don't need that because there is a relation between the two content type, the author is the same for the two node, but I was not able to combine the two node in one.

My solution Relation Module to combine the two node. I created a relation between the project and the project images node. In views I created a content type view with the field I need from the project type than I add the relation : Relation(node <-> node) add I add the field "Image(from Projet Image)" to display the image and Bingo I have one view output for two different node.

To make the relation automatic I created a Rules with Rules module. I fire the rule when a Projet is added or a Projet Image is added than I create the relation.

A quick help for rules 5 actions step
1st action : create a variable / create a list
2st action : fetch entity by property / node / Author
3rd action : place the fetch result in the list created at step 1 (you may have to create a lot) personally because the node hare limit to 1 per content type per user I just repeats the step 3 two time
4ft action : create a entity / relation / with the list created at step 1.

Those step have to be improve because those are my first step with Rules and I rules are not strong at all.

Hope it help someone.